# ASP.NET binding the listbox with dropdown

Tags: asp.net

I want to Bind ListBox with Dropdown ,on the selection of two or more records in listbox the value related to these records should reflect in dropdown??
Is it possible? Can Anybody tell
Thanx in advance

Comment: No "Wants" encouraged. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the event SelectedValueChanged with something like this:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedValueChanged);
```

Then in the method code the behavior you want:

`public void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code here playing with dropdownlist 
        }`